# UIImages will not resize based on device size

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, uikit

Okay so I created a UIButton on a UIScrollView and the I made the button have an image. My app is universal and the button is the same size for every device. I want it to change size based on the device size like it would if it was a SpriteNode with 3x, 2x, and 1x images. How can I do this?

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    let image = UIImage(named:"Buy5Button")
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (image?.size.width)!, (image?.size.height)!)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "something", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    scrollView.addSubview(button)
    self.view?.addSubview(scrollView)
```

Answer (score -1):

set the button frame to whatever size you want it to be (it will automatically be adapted to the device resolution). Then eventually set the image frame to be equal with the button frame.

I tend in such cases to set the background image of the button rather than the image, by doing it so I just need to define the button size and the background image gets scaled automatically...